# vue, binding two values from selected option by v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a working vue/laravel component where I'm using a v-for loop in a select box in order to create options from a vue array. This works properly.

My v-bind is properly binding the id of the selected option to featureID, but here's my question:

How can I also bind the feature.feature_name to another prop like featureName?

I don't see how I can bind the ID and the name of the selected option to two different props?

```
<select v-model="featureID">
  <option v-for="feature in features" v-bind:value="feature.id">
    @{{ feature.name }}
  </option>
</select>

data: {
    featureID: [''],
    features: [{id:1, name: 'test'}, {id:2, name: 'good}]
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean, feature.name and feature.id, right? That's what would match your data set.

Comment: sorry @user1015214, typo. Just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass more than one value in an option tag, but what you can do is pass the whole object as the value. You just need to pass `feature` as the prop

```
<select v-model="featureID">
  <option v-for="feature in features" v-bind:value="feature">
    @{{ feature.name }}
  </option>
</select>

data: {
    featureID: [''],
    features: [{id:1, name: 'test'}, {id:2, name: 'good}]
}
```

Then you will have the whole object and you'll be able to get the id and/or the name.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vjqf5ka/)

Comment: Your JS Fiddle doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `id` of a feature you can use index of selected list item.

```html
<select v-model="selectedIdx">
  <option v-for="(feature, index) in features" v-bind:value="index" :key="index">
    @{{ feature.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

```js
data: {
  selectedIdx: null,
  features: [
    {id:1, name: 'test'},
    {id:2, name: 'good'},
  ]
},
computed: {
  selectedFeature() {
    return this.features[this.selectedIdx]
  } 
}
```

Accessing `selectedFeature` you've got selected feature object.